# Why doesn't my GUI show squares after repaint()?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics2d

I posted this question a bit earlier and was told to make it SSCCE so here goes (if I can make any improvements feel free to let me know):
I'm wondering why when my button "confirm" is clicked the old squares disappear and the redrawn squares do not appear on my GUI (made with swing). The Squares class draws 200 spaced out squares with an ID (0, 1, 2, or 3 as String) inside obtained from a different class (for the purpose of this question, let's assume it is always 0 and not include that class). For clarification: Squares draws everything perfectly the first time (also retrieves the correct IDs), but I want it to redraw everything once the button is clicked with new IDs.

Code for Squares:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Squares extends JPanel{

private ArrayList<Rectangle> squares = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
private String stringID = "0";

public void addSquare(int x, int y, int width, int height, int ID) {
      Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
      squares.add(rect);
      stringID = Integer.toString(ID);
      if(ID == 0){
          stringID = "";
      }
}

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

  super.paintComponent(g);
  Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
  FontMetrics fm = g2.getFontMetrics();
  int fontAscent = fm.getAscent();
  g2.setClip(new Rectangle(0,0,Integer.MAX_VALUE,Integer.MAX_VALUE));
  for (Rectangle rect : squares) {
     g2.drawString(stringID, rect.x + 7, rect.y + 2 + fontAscent);
     g2.draw(rect);
  }
 }
}
```

Code for GUI:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUIReserver extends JFrame implements Runnable{

private int myID;
private JButton confirm = new JButton("Check Availability and Confirm Reservation");    
private JFrame GUI = new JFrame();
private Squares square; 

public GUIReserver(int i) {
    this.myID = i;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int rows = 50;
    int seatsInRow = 4;
    confirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                GUI.getContentPane().remove(square);
                square = new Squares();
                int spaceNum = 0;
                int rowNum = 0;
                int offsetX = 200;
                int offsetY = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < rows * seatsInRow; i++){
                    square.addSquare(rowNum * 31 + offsetX,spaceNum * 21 + 50 + offsetY,20,20, 0); //normally the 4th parameter here would retrieve the ID from the main class
                    rowNum++;
                    if(rowNum == 10){
                        rowNum = 0;
                        spaceNum++;
                    }
                    if(spaceNum == 2){
                        spaceNum = 3;
                        rowNum = 0;
                    }
                    if(spaceNum == 5){
                        spaceNum = 0;
                        offsetY += 140;
                    }
                }
                GUI.getContentPane().add(square); //this does not show up at all (could be that it wasn't drawn, could be that it is out of view etc...)
                GUI.repaint(); //the line in question
         }          
    });
    GUI.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GUI.setLocation(0,0);
    GUI.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    square = new Squares();
    int spaceNum = 0;
    int rowNum = 0;
    int offsetX = 200;
    int offsetY = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows * seatsInRow; i++){
        square.addSquare(rowNum * 31 + offsetX,spaceNum * 21 + 50 + offsetY,20,20, 0); //normally the 4th parameter here would retrieve the ID from the main class
        rowNum++;
        if(rowNum == 10){
            rowNum = 0;
            spaceNum++;
        }
        if(spaceNum == 2){
            spaceNum = 3;
            rowNum = 0;
        }
        if(spaceNum == 5){
            spaceNum = 0;
            offsetY += 140;
        }
    }
    GUI.getContentPane().add(square); //this shows up the way I wish
    GUI.add(confirm);
    GUI.pack();
    GUI.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: You just deleted your [recent previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222183/why-wont-squares-show-up-after-repaint) after I had labored to answer it and was continuing to work on it. Why did you do this? Why ask it again? You realize of course that we are volunteers, that are labors are on our own time, that you're doing this is very inconsiderate of you. Please re-open the previous question and improve it.  Don't re-ask it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels you're right, I didn't realize that. I reopened it and replaced my question with this one.

Comment: Call `GUI.revalidate()`, also there's no need to extend from `JFrame`

Comment: @ZainVirani: consider deleting this question.